# Use image as panel background

Tags: 12.04, unity, panel, customization

I installed Ubuntu 12.04. In the good old days where customizing your Ubuntu had no limits it was no big deal to change the background of the panel to an image of your choice.

How can i change the panel of my Adwaita Cupertino Unity L theme?

Can anyone help me out here?

---

I've tried to make the panel transparent. That really did not look very well. Its like the autohide of the application menu is just going black when not hovering the menu. So its under the White Title of the window

[image]

Comment: check this http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/03/how-to-easily-skin-ubuntus-unity-desktop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to have a look to the following files:

```
/usr/share/themes/Adwaita Cupertino L Unity/gtk-3.0/unity.css
/usr/share/themes/Adwaita Cupertino L Unity/gtk-3.0/unity-transparent.css
~/.themes/unity.css
```

All of them start at their very first with something like:

```
UnityPanelWidget,
.unity-panel {
    background-image: -gtk-gradient (linear, left top, left bottom,
                                     from (shade(@bg_color, 1.07)),                                     
                                     to (shade(@bg_color, 1.00)));
    border-width: 0;
    border-style: none;
}
```

With some CSS reminiscence, you could try with a custom image as a background (you'll adjust size if it works):

```
UnityPanelWidget,
.unity-panel {
       background-image: url("relative/path/to/your/some_pic.svg");
    border-width: 0;
    border-style: none;
}
```

Comment: This has been tried. I could not make it use any image. It shows full transparency when trying to use an image. Like i wrote i found a solution by editing the CSS. But i would really be nice if it would be easier like the old gnome-panel. Hopefully this is coming. I guess i will have to edit my themes untill that happens...

Answer (score 0):

A plausible workaround is to make your panel transparent in My Unity then add the image you want to use for the panel to the top of your background image. You can do this in GIMP utilising the layers feature.